# HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "HelloWorld" not found

Tags: javascript, terminal, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

so when I want to deploy my contract and write "npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli" in my terminal but it gives an error that says :

> HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "HelloWorld" not found.
> at Artifacts._handleWrongArtifactForContractName (/Users/**/hello-
> world/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:702:11)
> at Artifacts._getArtifactPathFromFiles (/Users/**/hello-
> world/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:827:19)
> at Artifacts._getArtifactPath (/Users/**/hello-world/node_modules/hardhat
> /src/internal/artifacts.ts:507:21)
> at Artifacts.readArtifact (/Users/**/hello-world/node_modules/hardhat
> /src/internal/artifacts.ts:71:26)
> at getContractFactory (/Users/**/hello-world/node_modules/@nomiclabs
> /hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:99:22)

Here's my `deploy.js` code :

```js
async function main() {
    const HelloWorld = await ethers.getContractFactory("HelloWorld");
 
    const hello_world = await HelloWorld.deploy("Hello World!");
    console.log("Contract deployed to address:", hello_world.address);
}
```

I even tried to put :

```js
const HelloWorld = await ethers.getContractFactory("HelloWorld.sol");
```

It should usually shows:

> Contract deployed to address: 0x ...

Can someone help me please? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to compile your contract.

```
npx hardhat compile
```